# responsive menu is showing behing content

Tags: html, css

I am redoing a friend's [website](http://isellrye.com/). 
The menu looks fine when it is full width but when you resize it down for responsive, the menu looks transparent and overlays the content. How can I fix this? I also have a fiddle here that I made https://jsfiddle.net/mlegg10/co62auy0/

```css
#menuBackground {
    background:#5EA5B9;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    text-align: center;
}
#menuContainer {
    text-align: center;
}
/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/
li {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-right:1px;
}

/*Style for menu links*/
li a {
    display:block;
    min-width:140px;
    height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
    font-family:Georgia;
    color:#fff;
    background:#5EA5B9;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

/*Hover state for top level links*/
li:hover a {
color: #036;     
     background:#fff
}

/*Prevent text wrapping*/
li ul li a {
    width:auto;
    min-width:100px;
    padding:0 20px
}

/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/
.show-menu {
    font-family:Georgia;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
    background:#5EA5B9;
    text-align:center;
    padding:16px 0;
    display:none;
    width:100%!important
}

/*Hide checkbox*/
input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none
}

/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu {
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto
}

/*Responsive Styles*/
@media screen and (max-width : 760px) {
    /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
    ul {
        position:static;
        display:none;
        white-space: initial;
    }
    
    /*Create vertical spacing*/
    li {
        margin-bottom:1px
    }
    
    /*Make all menu links full width*/
    ul li,li a {
        width:100%
    }
    
    /*Display 'show menu' link*/
    .show-menu {
        display:block
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="menuBackground">
    <div id="menuContainer">
        <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>        <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button" />
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="accommodations.html">Accommodations</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="amenities.html">Amenities</a>
            </li>
             <li><a href="rates.html">Rates</a>
            </li>
             <li><a href="links.html">Links</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            </li>
         </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: screenshot of what I mean if I didn't explain it correctly]

Comment: Its not an issue with the menu, its an issue with the content. Update your question to show css and html for the content, most likely a z-index problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding this worked for me:

```
#menuContainer {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

and for removing the space between the menu elements remove the 1px margin for the li-tags

Comment: Hey @mlegg I think you may have put the wrong answere right.
Could you please mark the correct answere that solved your problem?

Sorry to bother you, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set the z-index on the #menuBackground div. To do that you also have to specify a relative position.

```
#menuBackground {
    position:relative;
    z-index:10
}
```

Comment: that didn't work. I should have mentioned that I tried that originally too

Answer (score 0):

This is the final working code from all your help. Thanks!

```css
#menuBackground {
    background:#5EA5B9;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    text-align: center;
 }
#menuContainer {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    z-index: 1;
}
/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/
li {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

/*Style for menu links*/
li a {
    display:block;
    min-width:140px;
    height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
    font-family:Georgia;
    color:#fff;
    background:#5EA5B9;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

/*Hover state for top level links*/
li:hover a {
color: #036;     
     background:#fff
}

/*Prevent text wrapping*/
li ul li a {
    width:auto;
    min-width:100px;
    padding:0 20px
}

/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/
.show-menu {
    font-family:Georgia;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
    background:#5EA5B9;
    text-align:center;
    padding:16px 0;
    display:none;
    width:100%!important
}

/*Hide checkbox*/
input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none
}

/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu {
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto
}

/*Responsive Styles*/
@media screen and (max-width : 760px) {
    /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
    ul {
        position:static;
        display:none;
        white-space: initial;
    }
    
    /*Make all menu links full width*/
    ul li,li a {
        width:100%
    }
    
    /*Display 'show menu' link*/
    .show-menu {
        display:block
    }
}
```